# Incorrect appearance of bar positions - d3.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, d3.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to generate a bar chart with d3.js in angular.js - ionic app.The bar positioning is incorrect.Here is the screen shot

[image: Incorrect positioning of bars]

But I need similar to this

[image]

Here is the javascript code

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
   width = $("#chart_div").width() - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = $("#chart_div").height() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{"scenario":"Expected","hours":32},{"scenario":"Actual","hours":16}];

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.scenario; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.hours; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Hours");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.scenario); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.hours); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.hours); });

function type(d) {
  d.hours = +d.hours;
  return d;
}
```

Created fiddle is at [d3 chart](http://jsfiddle.net/prodeveloper/da53jmwd/2/)
Please help me out

Comment: Strangely working fine in iOS device but browser emulator and Android device are showing incorrect bar position

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this same problem, I realized that the "rect" wasn't taking the right dimensions of width and height.

Try to change the bar class (change the name) which is probably in conflict with another existing one in your css library.

Comment: In my case it turned out to be the `.bar` class that I used for the rects that created the conflict . Renaming it to some other name say `.bar1` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues.It turned out that the `.bar` class that I was using conflicted with some ionic css.Renaming it to `.bar1` did the trick for me.